# Error with wxpython sizers

Tags: python, wxpython

I am not sure how I should size this, I have been trying to use sizer but it seems i am doing something wrong all the time.

Basically i have this code:

```
self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Create New", pos=(25,250))
```

and i would like to use a sizer with it. So it will adjust its position always to the window. The initial starting position is 25, 250. The height of the initial window is 400.
I would like the button to adjust accordingly to the window changes.

Thank you, please comment if you have any questions or need clarification.

Comment: What is your sizer code so far? You need to initialize something like a `wx.BoxSizer` to begin with. Also, specifying a position in the element is unnecessary if you're going to be placing it in a sizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a wxglade automatically-generated code showing how to use a `wx.BoxSizer`.
It is simply a Frame with a panel widget. You can change the panel with your button and it will work perfectly. The idea is that you could add other widgets as it is done for the `wx.Panel` in:

```
sizer_2.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
```

this produce your widgets being situated in a row. If you want another disposition you could use a different sizer, You can also add sizers with widgets to other sizers. The parameters in sizer.Add() determine the borders and behavior of the sizer. You should check wxPython/wxglade documentation for that. Anyway, the estructure is always like the one below:

```
import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade

class MyFrame1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU| wx.CAPTION
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        ------ create other widgets here ------

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_2")
        self.SetMinSize((300,200))
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__do_layout
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        ------ add other widgets or even sizers to the sizer here ------
        self.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        sizer_2.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame1(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```